# Where in ש״ס who one find the adage, “He who suggests the idea should carry it out”?

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara

If I can recall it would be found in Kedushin (besides others)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

סנהדרין פב א

> קריינא דאיגרתא איהו ליהוי פרוונקא

The reader of the letter (that contains the orders), let him be the one to carry it out.

The context there is Pinchas telling Moshe, didn't you taught us that if one is having intercourse with Aramine women, is to be killed by zealots? and that's Moshe answer to him.

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel yeah my question was focused more on the phrase than the source it is cited, I used Kiddushin because I think that’s where I learned but I don’t necessarily need the source there

Answer (score 6):

[Bava Metzia 83b](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.83b.8?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi), [Sanhedrin 82a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.82a.13?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), and [Sanhedrin 96a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.96a.12?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).